# Access the destination property name to be mapped in IValueResolver

Tags: c#, automapper

I'd like to reuse the same IValueResolver for several properties for the same class, all three properties to be mapped pass for the same process, so I don't want to repeat a code that could be almost the same.

I want to do something like this:

```
CreateMap<AlertLine, AlertLineDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.BusinessArea, opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver>())

CreateMap<AlertLine, AlertLineDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Division, opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver>())

CreateMap<AlertLine, AlertLineDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.SubDivision, opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver>())


public class MyResolver : IValueResolver<AlertLine, AlertLineDto, string>
    {
        private readonly ICatalogService _catalogService;
        public BusinessAreaResolver(ICatalogService catalogService)
        {
            _catalogService = catalogService;
        }
        public string Resolve(AlertLine source, AlertLineDto destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            // How to access the destination property name to be mapped?
            // BusinessArea, Division, SubDivision, and so on...

            string val = string.Empty;
            var variant = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AddlInformation>(source.AddlDimension);
            if (variant.BUSINESS_AREA_ID > 0)
            {
                var businessArea = _catalogService.GetCachedBusinessAreaById(variant.BUSINESS_AREA_ID);
                val = businessArea?.Description;

            }
            return val;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try using `IMemberValueResolver` instead of `IValueResolver`. [Customizing the source value supplied to the resolver](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-value-resolvers.html#customizing-the-source-value-supplied-to-the-resolver)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `IMemberValueResolver` instead of `IValueResolver`

Send the property name instead of the actual source value if the logic varies for different member.

```
CreateMap<AlertLine, AlertLineDto>()
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.BusinessArea,
    opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver, string>(p => "BusinessArea"))) 
    //opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver, string>(source => source.BusinessArea))
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.Division,
    opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver, string>(p => "Division")))
   //opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver, string>(source => source.Division))
.ForMember(
    dest => dest.SubDivision,
    opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver, string>(p => "SubDivision"));
    //opt => opt.MapFrom<MyResolver, string>(source => source.SubDivision))
```

The `propertyName` parameter will help you identify which mapping is currently called based on the value of the parameter. The `returnValue` will be mapped to the appropriate destination member

```
public class MyResolver : IMemberValueResolver<AlertLine, AlertLineDto, string, string>
{    
    public string Resolve(AlertLine source, AlertLineDto destination, string propertyName, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        string sourceValue = string.Empty;
        string returnValue = string.Empty;

        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "BusinessArea":
                 sourceValue = source.BusinessArea;
                 //returnValue = Some Logic here
                break;
            case "Division":
                sourceValue = source.Division;
                //returnValue = Some Logic here
                break;
            case "SubDivision":
                sourceValue = source.SubDivision;
                //returnValue = Some Logic here
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }          
        return returnValue;
    }    
}
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks for the help!

Comment: How to do the same thing ForAllMembers I want to pass the Param name